# Laravel Relationships - Questions, Answers and userAnswers

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, relationship

I have some problem, i have 3 tables:

```
questions

id | text

answers

id | question_id | text

user_answers

id | user_id | question_id | text
```

Example records:

```
questions

1 | Gender
2 | Age (input type, answers not exist in answers table)
3 | What kind of pets do you have?

answers

1 | 1 | Male
2 | 2 | Female
3 | 3 | Cat
4 | 3 | Dog
5 | 3 | Parrot

user_answers

1 | 100 | 1 | 1
2 | 100 | 2 | 30
3 | 100 | 3 | 4
3 | 100 | 3 | 5
```

So, I wonder if exists the way to do relationships without RAW SQL (with joins etc.) in models. For example, something like this:

```
    $questions = Question::with('userAnswer')->where('user_id', 100); 
    foreach($questions as $q)
    {
      echo $question->text;
      foreach($question->userAnswers as $ans)
      {
        echo $ans->text 
      }
    }
```

And result:

```
Gender
 - male
Age
 - 30
What kind of pets do you have?
 - dog
 - parrot
```

You know what I mean? Some ideas? :)
Thank You for Your attention!

EDITED:

This not work (relation stdAnswer is empty),

```
    $questions = LucidStandardQuestion::with('userAnswers.stdAnswer')->find(x);
```

this work:

```
    LucidStandardQuestion::with('userAnswers')->find(x)
```

and in model LucidStandarQuestion:

```
    public function userAnswers()
    {
       $uid = 1576;
        
       return $this->hasMany(LucidUserAnswer::Class, 'question_id')->where('user_id' , $uid);
    }
```

and in model LucidUserAnswer:

```
    public function stdAnswer()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(LucidStandardAnswer::class, 'question_id');
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

It's a simple [hasMany](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many) relation:

```
class Question extends Model
{
    public function userAnswer()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(LucidUserAnswer::class,'question_id');
    }
}
```

Now your code may look like:

```
$questions = Question::with(['userAnswer' => function($query)
{
    $query->where('user_id', 100)->with('answer');
}])->get();
```

and in LucidUserAnswer model you should make the relation

```
 class LucidUserAnswer extends Model
 {
     public function answer()
     {
         return $this->belongsTo(Answer::class,'text');
     }
 }
```

Comment: Yes, I have UserAnswer. And I have relation:  

`public function userAnswers()
    {
        // $uid = auth()->id();
        $uid = 1576;
        
        return $this->hasMany(LucidUserAnswer::Class, 'question_id')->where('user_id' , $uid);
    }
`  

but when i do:<br/>
`
$question = LucidStandardQuestion::with('userAnswers')->find(3);
`
  
i dont have name (text) of the answer (dog, parrot, cat... etc.) only value of user answer.  
  
:(

Comment: that because the name is inside 'answers' table, not inside user_answers

Comment: I know, and i have to do sql question to all answers to get text?    
  
PS. How i can do break line? :) Two spaces not working...

Comment: my brain is cracking, I try to do it from 7am. Not work. A will update a question, in this comments is heavy to read this...